# Aligment of li element in PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I try to convert HTML to DOCX with PHPWord library (phpoffice/phpword:v0.16)

```
$html = "<html><head></head>
<body>
<ol>
<li style='text-align: left'>line</li>
<li style='text-align: right'>line</li>
<li style='text-align: right'>line</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>";

$section = $phpWord->addSection(array('pageNumberingStart' => 1));
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html, true, false);
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
```

Docx file is generated properly, but all text inside `<li>` elements is aligned to the left:
[image: aligned all to the left]

Any idea how to align text in docx file, defined in style attribute in HTML? 
The result should be:
[image: aligned to the left and right]

Comment: try `<li align="right">line</li>`

Comment: Nope `<li align="right">line</li>` does not work. It's the same as `<li style='text-align: left'>line</li>` :-(

Answer (score 0):

use css.

```
li {
  float: right;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Then alignment will be always on left. Why should I use `float: left;` ?

Comment: sorry there is mistake use float:right. li will show right side.

Comment: But first I need on left, second and third on right side.